# a better way to import modules from other folders in python

Tags: python, python-import, modularity, directory-structure

My current way of importing scripts I've written looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../')
from lib.helper import file_manager
```

because my folder structure looks like this:

```
|
├── lib               
│   ├── upm
│   └── helper
|       └── file_manager.py     <- the imported file.
│
└── src
    └── deployment
        └── cli.py              <- the executed file.
```

So when `cli.py` runs it has to append the root folder onto the `sys.path` before it can include anything from `lib`. If I move `cli.py` around, I have to change this line to reflect how nested it is: `sys.path.append('../../')`

There has got to be a better way to import modules that are in the same project. Because of this bad pattern, I find myself fighting with the current working directory of my project way too much.

What would you do if you were me?

Comment: can you add lib to your pythonpath? Then control the file_manager with an __init__.py file in the upm folder so you can do like import from upm.helper import file_manager

Comment: The ideal thing to do is to deploy by `setup.py`/`pip install .` rather than just by copying the source tree. Then, assuming you get all the `setuptools` stuff right, you end up with your libs in site-packages and your scripts as scripts that just use the libs out of site-packages and it all just works.

Comment: I have tried having __init__.py in my case and failed. I ended up using sys.path.insert(0, '../pathhere/'). I looking also for a better solution;)

Comment: @abarnert I'm leaning towards that approach, the problem is I'm making automated docker containers so I'll have to install `pip install .` those with a python file which means the python file in charge of installing these dependencies itself still has this problem... so I was hoping there was an alternative 'ideal solution'

Comment: @LegitStack For that case, you can `pip install` into a portable virtual environment, then deploy that whole env into the docker container. (That way you also guarantee that the container has the exact right third-party libs, etc., without having to vendor them all into your source tree.)

Comment: @abarnert perhaps that's the best way - we were treating the docker container itself as the virtual environment, but as long as we have a process whereby we update the docker with the latest virtual environment (as we change it a lot in dev) I guess that would be best practice. thanks

Comment: @LegitStack I’ve worked on projects that did it both ways, and if you can use a portable env (because your dev boxes and CI setup and containers are all compatible—which basically just means ensuring any extension modules come from manylinux wheels), it’s a lot simpler. (If you can’t do that, you can still write an env-builder script that’s used by container creation, and CI, and dev setup—but that’s extra work, and makes upgrading packages more painful too.)

Comment: You can use `python setup.py develop` if pip is an issue (I'd also suggest using `pip install -e .` if you're using pip).